Setting flyway schema - postgres database
I have an issue while trying to set the schema for a flyway migration. This is for a generic migration that I plan to run in several different schemas.
Migration looks like this:
CREATE TABLE foo (
    fooid smallint NOT NULL
);

flyway.conf
flyway.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
flyway.user=
flyway.locations=filesystem:../../generic, filesystem:../migrations
flyway.cleanDisabled=False
flyway.defaultSchema=testschema
flyway.schemas=testschema

And getting this error:
Message    : ERROR: no schema has been selected to create in
